# Can't able to take a build of my iOS flutter app, but able to run the iOS flutter app in my iPhone + flutter + testflight

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store, testflight

im trying to deploy my 7th version of my app into testing in testflight.
i did run the below code

```
flutter clean
rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
```

and its encountering the below image error

[image]

the problem is that i check my apple developers account and checked my Certificates and Identitifers for this bundle id and its expiring next year only,
and i also checked my xcode Signing and Capabilities and selected the correct profile and tried to build the flutter app bundle.

when i did my version 6 test release i dint face this issue, but when im trying to do the 7th version release im facing this issue.

is there any way to resolve this, i need to deploy this app in app store.

Comment: i resolved the issue, i opened my ios folder in XCode, and under signing and capabilities i selected my profile id in Debug, Release and Profile tab.
and then i runned the rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios. the bundle got created.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message you are getting, it seems like the app identifier is already taken. Try changing it and the error should go away.